# Need to update a column by an id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change the values (from 0 to 1) in a column called "payscale" in a table called "person" but I only want to change the rows by the person_id from another table called staff_role_allocation, and nothing I have tried works

```
SELECT person.person_id, person.payscale 
FROM person 
INNER JOIN staff_role_allocation ON 
person.person_id = staff_role_allocation.person_id 
WHERE (UPDATE person
SET person.payscale='1')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps <mysql>?)

Comment: @jarlh certainly MySQL, hence the wrongly used tag `phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because people seem to be struggling with it, the following is an example of valid syntax. Whether or not it's the query you're after is another question entirely...

```
UPDATE person p
  JOIN staff_role_allocation a
    ON p.person_id = a.person_id 
   SET p.payscale = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below - your syntax is wrong for mysql

```
UPDATE person p
INNER JOIN staff_role_allocation ON 
p.person_id = staff_role_allocation.person_id 
SET p.payscale='1'
```

Comment: UPDATE p from person
INNER JOIN staff_role_allocation ON 
person.person_id = staff_role_allocation.person_id 
SET person.payscale='1'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from person
INNER JOIN staff_role_allocation ON
person.person_id = staff_role' at line 1

Comment: Why not test code before posting. This helps nobody.

Answer (score -2):

It probably works like this:

```
    UPDATE person SET person.payscale='1'
    FROM person INNER JOIN staff_role_allocation
    ON person.person_id = staff_role_allocation.person_id
```

Tell me if it works

Comment: It probably doesn't

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM person INNER JOIN staff_rolle_allocation
    ON person.person_id = staff_r' at line 2

Comment: There was a typo in the staff_role table.

Comment: No. This is not MySQL syntax.